# How to copy a row from a data frame to a matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix, row, frame

In Microsoft Open R 3.3, how can I copy a row from a database query (returns a data frame) into a row of a matrix?  I know I could do it element-by-element, but I should be able to copy a row at a time.  I can't, though:

```
> m = matrix(0, nrow=2, ncol=3)
> dim(m)
[1] 2 3
> dim(m[1,])
NULL
> f = dbGetQuery("SELECT id, name, age FROM users")
> dim(f)
[1] 300 3
> dim(f[1,])
[1] 1 3
> m[1,] = f[1,]
> m[1,]
Error in m[1, ] : incorrect number of dimensions
> dim(m)
NULL
> m[1,] = f[1,]
Error in m[1, ] = f[1, ] : 
  incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
```

Converting f to as.matrix(f) doesn't help.

Why is dim(m[1,]) "NULL" instead of "1 3"?

Why does m[1,] = f[1,] wreck the data structure of m the first time (changes dim(m) to NULL), but not report an error until the second time I do it?

I suspect this has to do with the fact that a data frame row can contain different types, while a matrix row can't.  One column of the frame is character data, while the others are integers.

Comment: m[1,] is just a numeric vector. If you want to keep the dimension then first read `?'['` and note the use of the 'drop' argument. The structure was not "wrecked". You are simply misinterpreting the output.

Comment: I say the structure is wrecked because it has lost its dimensions internally. dim(m) returns NULL after but not before that assignment.  Editing now to add that info to the question.

Comment: We don't really know that `f` was a dataframe from the evidence supplied so far. You should offer the results of `dput( f[1, ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to assign the values after unlisting `f[1,]`, since `f[1,]` returns a one row data frame which is a list, `m[1,]` returns an atomic vector and this answers the question *Why is dim(m[1,]) "NULL" instead of "1 3"?* because a 1D atomic vector doesn't have the dimension attribute. Trying to assign a list to an atomic vector causes problem:

```
m = matrix(0, nrow=2, ncol=3)
f = data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 2:4, z = 3:5)
m
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    0    0    0
#[2,]    0    0    0
m[1,] = unlist(f[1,])
m
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    2    3
#[2,]    0    0    0

class(m[1,])
#[1] "numeric"
class(f[1,])
#[1] "data.frame"
```